# LotusScript cannot get file attachment from email

Tags: lotus-notes, mime, lotus-domino, lotusscript, richtext

I had never run into this problem, but I cannot get a handle on a file attachment on an email.  I have code that can either search the document for Embedded Objects or search a field for Embedded Objects -- neither of them are returning the file.  I can see the file on the email and I can see the $FILE field which contains the file attachment.

Here is the code:

```
    Function FileDetachFiles(doc As NotesDocument, fieldName As String, getFromField As Integer) As Variant

    On Error Goto ProcessError

    Dim s As NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim rtItem As NotesRichTextItem
    Dim fileToExtract As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileArray() As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim embedObjects As Variant
    Dim attachFile As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Set s = New NotesSession    
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Const fileImport = "C:\"
    attachFile = False

    'Let's see if there are attached files...
    If getFromField = True Then
        'Locate field and get files...
        If doc.HasEmbedded Then
            If doc.HasItem(fieldName) Then          
                'Set the first field...
                Set rtItem = doc.GetFirstItem(fieldName)
                embedObjects = rtItem.EmbeddedObjects
                If Isarray(embedObjects) Then
                    Forall Files In rtItem.EmbeddedObjects
                        If Files.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
                            fileName = Files.Source
                            fileToExtract = fileImport & fileName
                            Redim Preserve fileArray(x)
                            fileArray(x) = fileToExtract
                            x = x + 1
                            Call Files.ExtractFile(fileToExtract)   
                            attachFile = True               
                        End If          
                    End Forall
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else    
        x = 0       
        'Go through doc looking for all embedded objects...
        If doc.HasEmbedded Then
            Forall o In doc.EmbeddedObjects
                If o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
                    fileName = o.Name
                    fileToExtract = fileImport & fileName
                    Call o.ExtractFile(fileToExtract)
                    Redim Preserve fileArray(x)
                    fileArray(x) = fileToExtract
                    x = x + 1
                    attachFile = True       
                End If      
            End Forall
        End If      
    End If

    If attachFile = True Then       
        FileDetachFiles = fileArray
    End If

    Exit Function
ProcessError:
    message = "Error (" & Cstr(Err) & "): " & Error$ & " on line " & Cstr(Erl) & " in GlobalUtilities: " & Lsi_info(2) & "."
    Messagebox message, 16, "Error In Processing..."
    Exit Function
End Function
```

I tried both routines above -- passing the $FILE and Body field names, as well as searching the document.  It does not find any file attachments.

I even tried this:
[Extracting attachments as MIME using LotusScript](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21225634)

Which did not find any MIME on the document.

I have never run into this problems -- any ideas would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had that before, but unfortunately do not remember, where it comes from, it might have to do something with V2- Style Attachments coming from Domino Websites...
Try Evaluate( @AttachmentNames ) to get a Variant containing the names of all attachments. Then loop through this with a Forall- loop and try the NotesDocument.getAttachment( strLoopValue ) - Function to get a handle to the attachment. 
For further info read [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21100615) and follow the links on that page, especially [this one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21104835)

Code would be something like this:

```
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim varAttachmentNamens as Variant
Dim object as NotesEmbeddedObject    

REM "Get the document here"
varAttachmentNames = Evaluate( "@AttachmentNames" , doc )
Forall strAttachmentName in varAttachmentNames
  Set object = doc.GetAttachment( strAttachmentName )
  REM "Do whatever you want..."
End Forall
```

Comment: That worked -- thanks!  Here is the final code I came up with:

Comment: attachNames = Evaluate( "@AttachmentNames" , doc )
 Forall values In attachNames
  attachName = values
  Set object = doc.GetAttachment(attachName)
  If object.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
   fileName = object.Name
   fileToExtract = fileImport & fileName
   Call object.ExtractFile(fileToExtract)
   Redim Preserve fileArray(x)
   fileArray(x) = fileToExtract
   x = x + 1
  End If  
 End Forall