# Object or with variable not set - save attachments from Lotus notes

Tags: vba, object, lotus

I am trying to get a code that saves the attachments of a specific Lotus Notes Folder and saves it to a local folder (withouth deleting the email or attachment from Lotus Notes). But I keep on getting the error message: "Object or with variable not set" 
I have already changed the code several times but I just don't get what I am doing wrong. I am new to VBA and do not understand all of the code. I would be very thankful for your help.

Thank you!

```
Sub Save_Attachments()

Const stPath As String = "c:\Attachments"
Const EMBED_ATTACHMENT As Long = 1454
Const RICHTEXT As Long = 1

Dim noSession As Object
Dim noDatabase As Object
Dim noView As Object
Dim noDocument As Object
Dim noNextDocument As Object

Dim vaItem As Variant
Dim vaAttachment As Variant

Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", " mail2\cbarrios.nsf")
Set noView = noDatabase.GetView("AAA")
Set noDocument = noView.GetFirstDocument
Do Until noDocument Is Nothing
Set noNextDocument = noView.GetNextDocument(noDocument)
If noDocument.HasEmbedded Then
  Set vaItem = noDocument.GetFirstItem("Body")
  If vaItem.Type = RICHTEXT Then
    For Each vaAttachment In vaItem.EmbeddedObjects
     If vaAttachment.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
        With vaAttachment
        .ExtractFile stPath & vaAttachment.Name
        End With
     End If
    Next vaAttachment
  End If
End If
Set noDocument = noNextDocument
Loop

Set noNextDocument = Nothing
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noView = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: At what line this error appears? It should be highlighted in yellow.

Answer (score 0):

The given code should work for every mail that is in Notes Richtextformat. 
It will most probably throw the mentioned error for every mime- message.

Unfortunately the way to get attachments is different for the different formats. 
BUT: There is one universal solution that works for both of them.

```vb
Dim varAttachmentNamens as Variant

REM "Get the document here"
varAttachmentNames = noSession.Evaluate( "@AttachmentNames" , noDocument )
 For Each strAttachmentName in varAttachmentNames
  Set vaAttachment = noDocument.GetAttachment( strAttachmentName )
  If vaAttachment.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
    Call vaAttachment.ExtractFile stPath & vaAttachment.Name
  End With
End Forall
```

Check out [this stackexchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302597/lotusscript-cannot-get-file-attachment-from-email) or [this link at IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21100615) for further details.

Comment: Thank you Torsten for your answer. I have checked the links you sent me, however (as I mentioned I am new at this) I still don't get it to work. I get an error message : Error when compiling (I hope this is the right translation). It shows me the error on the line:  
 Forall strAttachmentName in varAttachmentNames I am also not sure I am putting your code on the right position (within mine).

Comment: Sorry, i just copied lotusscript code. Most if it works the same in VBA. It has to be `For Each`, not `Forall`. I fixed that in the example above.